# compute gradients per instance of minibatch

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'd like to compute the gradients per instance of a minibatch. The end goal is to weight the gradients differently based on what input_i was in the minibatch. However, map_fn is currently giving me the following error:

```
ValueError: The two structures don't have the same number of elements.

First structure (1 elements): <dtype: 'float32'>

Second structure (2 elements): [<tf.Tensor 'map/while/gradients/MatMul_grad/MatMul_1:0' shape=(4, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'map/while/gradients/add_grad/Reshape_1:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32>]
```

I think that the error is b/c the response of compute_grad_i is of a different shape than the loss_i input. Here is code to reproduce the error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 4])
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])

W = tf.get_variable('w', shape=[4, 1])
b = tf.get_variable('b', shape=[1, 1])

y_pred = tf.matmul(x, W) + b

loss = (y_pred - y) ** 2

trainable_vars = tf.trainable_variables()
compute_grad_i = lambda loss_i: tf.gradients(loss_i, trainable_vars)
grads = tf.map_fn(compute_grad_i, loss)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
feed_dict = {x: np.random.randn(3, 4), y: np.random.randn(3, 1)}
g = sess.run([grads], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Computing gradients inside of map_fn is a known issue w/ tensorflow as per [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7643)

Here is an ugly way of weighting your gradients per batch

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 4])
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])

W = tf.get_variable('w', shape=[4, 1])
b = tf.get_variable('b', shape=[1, 1])

y_pred = tf.matmul(x, W) + b

loss = (y_pred - y) ** 2

trainable_vars = tf.trainable_variables()

g = tf.gradients(loss, trainable_vars)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

x_in = np.random.randn(3, 4)
y_in = np.random.randn(3, 1)

gs = None
mini_i_w = [1,2,3]
for i, [x_i, y_i] in enumerate(zip(x_in, y_in)):
    feed_dict = {x: np.reshape(x_i, [-1, x_in.shape[1]]), y: np.reshape(y_i, [-1, y_in.shape[1]])}
    g_i = sess.run(g, feed_dict=feed_dict)

    if gs is None:
        gs = mini_i_w[i] * g_i
    else:
        gs = [gs[k] + mini_i_w[i] * g_i[k] for k in range(len(g_i))]
```